# Doctor Who recent reference to Tegan

Tags: doctor-who, episode-identification

A recent Doctor Who made a comment about an Australian who got stuck on the Tardis, obviously a reference to Tegan. But can anyone tell me which Doctor and episode it was in?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A seach of the chakoteya.net transcripts gives ([source](http://www.chakoteya.net/DoctorWho/33-12.htm)):

> The Tardis materialises in a cobbled alley, in sepia with tickly music in the background all the way through.)
>
> DOCTOR: Okay, so. Not London 1893. Yorkshire 1893. Near enough.
>
> CLARA: You're making a habit of this, getting us lost.
>
> DOCTOR: Sorry. It's much better than it used to be. Ooo, I once spent a hell of a long time trying to get a gobby Australian to Heathrow Airport. 
>   (That would be Tegan Jovanka.)
>
> CLARA: What for?
>
> DOCTOR: Search me. Anyway

Which is from [The Crimson Horror](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt2204480/) with Matt Smith's Doctor.

Comment: Worth noting: the next line here was "brave heart, Clara" - a catchphrase used with Tegan.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tK4euPP5ebE

Comment: @Will Your comment is everything.